# Special Java characters in String

Tags: java, string, unicode, character

I am confused, I have Strings in Java like that:

```
String str = "str \u0923 something else";
```

How to handle characters like casual characters (not like Java special characters), I mean that `str[4]` is `'\'` not a `ण` (in unicode `\u0923` = `ण)` unicode character. I am asking for a mechanical solution not manual.

Comment: `I asking for a mechanical solution not manual` Huh? Are you asking how to escape a backslash?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve. What is the input, what is the output, and what is wrong with what you have right now?

Comment: That is a `String` literal. The characters `\u0923` get converted at compile time. At runtime, the value of the `String` is `"str ण something else"`. If you want a `\`, escape it.

Comment: ok, input String str = "str \u0923 something else"; output str.charAt(0) is 's' , str.charAt(1) is 't', str.charAt(2) is 'r', str.charAt(3) is ' ', str.charAt(4) is '\', str.charAt(5) is 'u', str.charAt(6) is '0', str.charAt(7) is '9' and so on...

Comment: If that is the output you really want, then you must escape the `'\'` character in your string literal using `"\\"`, eg: `String str = "str \\u0923 something else";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JLS says that [unicode backslash escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) are to be interpretted as if the file was written with the actual character encoded there instead. It's a source level replacements, and has nothing to do with String literals.

For example, here is perfectly compilable Java where unicode escapes are used instead of quotes and semicolons:

```
class test {
    String a = \u0022hello world"\u003B
}
```

This means that given a String reference, **there is no way to determine if the original source file contained `ण` or `\u0923`** in its assignment.

It's similar to how there is no way to differentiate which of `s1` and `s2` was assigned with a `+` in it:

```
String s1 = "hello " + "world";
String s2 = "hello world";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String str = "str \\u0923 something else";
```

and it will print out:

```
str \u0923 something else
```

and not

```
str ण something else
```

Comment: Yes, but how to add that backslash automatically?

Answer (score 0):

**Backshash in `char`s or `String`s in Java always represent escape sequence.** If you want the standard `'\'` character, you have to use `'\\'` or `"\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your string into character array using- str.toCharArray()
then you will be able to handle with each character individually after mapping hash code with it.
For example-

```
String str=str\u0923;
char str[]=str.tocharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
int str=((Character) str[i]).hashCode();
```